Docker image is not running getting error
Dockerfile:
FROM node:22-alpine3.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm i

COPY .env.sample .env.local

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm","run","dev","--","--host"]

ERROR
npm warn deprecated domexception@4.0.0: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm warn deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.11.14: Use @eslint/config-array instead
npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead

> frontend@0.0.0 prepare
> cd .. && npm install

npm error Tracker "idealTree" already exists
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-05T21_26_45_767Z-debug-0.log
npm error code 1
npm error path /app
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c cd .. && npm install
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-05T21_18_16_441Z-debug-0.log


Please update your question to include a minimal-repro of your issue not just the Dockerfile and errors. We're unable to determine what project code is copied (by e.g. COPY . .) and can only infer the content of package.json.

Running npm install from the filesystem root directory seems to cause this problem; also see npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists while creating the Docker image for Node project.  The cd .. && npm install (in a package.json script?) seems to be trying to install something that's not included in the image.
